# Dynamically generated hash keys are not displaying correctly when using render json in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

`render json:` is not displaying my hash key correctly and I am not sure exactly why.  I will post the controller code and the view output below.

```
    merger = {}

    stops = OpsHeader.joins(
        ops_stop_rec: :driver_header
      )
    .select(
        :pb_net_rev,
        :pbbname,
        :ops_driver1,
        :pb_id,
        :ops_stop_id,
        :dh_first_name,
        :dh_last_name
      )
      .where(
        :ops_stop_rec => {
            ops_arrive_time: params[:startDate] .. params[:endDate]
        })


    OpsStopRec.joins(
        :ops_line_items
      ).select(
        :opl_amount,
        :ops_type,
        :ops_stop_id,
        :ops_order_id,
        :ops_driver1
      )
      .where(
        :ops_stop_rec => {
            ops_arrive_time: params[:startDate] .. params[:endDate]
        }
      ).each do |lines|
        stops.each do |stop|
          if (lines.ops_stop_id == stop.ops_stop_id && lines.ops_driver1 == stop.ops_driver1)
              merger[stop] = (merger[stop] ||= []) << lines
          end
          if (!merger.key?(stop))
              merger[stop] = merger[stop]
          end
        end
      end

render json: merger
```

Here is the actual output of my `render json:`:

```
#<OpsHeader:0x0a61cdd8>: [
{
ops_stop_id: 260772,
ops_order_id: "129215.0",
ops_type: "P",
ops_driver1: 97,
opl_amount: "625.0"
},
{
ops_stop_id: 260772,
ops_order_id: "129215.0",
ops_type: "P",
ops_driver1: 97,
opl_amount: "112.5"
}
],
```

If I am looping over the record collection and using the looped elements as keys in my `merger` hash, how come it is still not displaying correctly in the view?

What is odd is the `values` that you see are also from a looped `collection` but they seem to display correctly.  It will display correctly in `binding.pry()` but not in the view.

Any ideas?

Let me give you a better example of what I am referring to.  This is close to what I want but it's still not rendered to `json`.  In this case, I am using the `attributes` method to display the `key`:

```
{"pb_id"=>0.133204e6, "pbbname"=>"AMARR INC", "pb_net_rev"=>0.24259e4, "ops_driver1"=>61, "ops_stop_id"=>268970, "dh_first_name"=>"MARK", "dh_last_name"=>"STAYTON"}: null,
{"pb_id"=>0.133203e6, "pbbname"=>"AMARR INC", "pb_net_rev"=>0.251647e4, "ops_driver1"=>89, "ops_stop_id"=>268966, "dh_first_name"=>"RICHARD", "dh_last_name"=>"STROEMER"}: null,
{"pb_id"=>0.133203e6, "pbbname"=>"AMARR INC", "pb_net_rev"=>0.251647e4, "ops_driver1"=>89, "ops_stop_id"=>268967, "dh_first_name"=>"RICHARD", "dh_last_name"=>"STROEMER"}: null,
{"pb_id"=>0.133203e6, "pbbname"=>"AMARR INC", "pb_net_rev"=>0.251647e4, "ops_driver1"=>89, "ops_stop_id"=>268968, "dh_first_name"=>"RICHARD", "dh_last_name"=>"STROEMER"}: null,
{"pb_id"=>0.133204e6, "pbbname"=>"AMARR INC", "pb_net_rev"=>0.24259e4, "ops_driver1"=>61, "ops_stop_id"=>268971, "dh_first_name"=>"MARK", "dh_last_name"=>"STAYTON"}: null,
{"pb_id"=>0.133204e6, "pbbname"=>"AMARR INC", "pb_net_rev"=>0.24259e4, "ops_driver1"=>61, "ops_stop_id"=>268972, "dh_first_name"=>"MARK", "dh_last_name"=>"STAYTON"}: null,
{"pb_id"=>0.133204e6, "pbbname"=>"AMARR INC", "pb_net_rev"=>0.24259e4, "ops_driver1"=>61, "ops_stop_id"=>268973, "dh_first_name"=>"MARK", "dh_last_name"=>"STAYTON"}: [
{
ops_stop_id: 268973,
ops_order_id: "133204.0",
ops_type: "P",
ops_driver1: 61,
opl_amount: "2375.9"
},
{
ops_stop_id: 268973,
ops_order_id: "133204.0",
ops_type: "P",
ops_driver1: 61,
opl_amount: "50.0"
},
{
ops_stop_id: 268973,
ops_order_id: "133204.0",
ops_type: "P",
ops_driver1: 61,
opl_amount: "0.0"
}
```

As you can see, some are nested and others have `null` values, which is fine.

Comment: You should add an example of what would be a correct output. Also, why does your hash contains class instances as keys?

Comment: You just asked my own question :D.  I want those class instances to be objects.  Essentially, I want it to display a nested JSON object with the class keys being just another object like the values you see above.  I haven't played with RoR in a long time, but I am confused as to why when I push those same class instances into an array, they display as JSON objects but not as keys?

Comment: Putting objects as keys is pretty non-standard and isn't really gonna work smoothly ... it's better to change your JSON response structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in JSON format, a key has to be a string. Just that ruby allows you to have pretty much anything as a key of the hash, doesn't mean it will be compatible with the JSON standard. I will suggest you to change the format of your data so you can produce something like this:

```
# It is JSON, not ruby 
{
  "ops_headers": [ # each of your OpsHeader instances
    { 
      "pb_id": 133204,
      "pbbname": "AMARR INC",
      "pb_net_rev": 2425.9,
      "ops_driver1": 61,
      "ops_stop_id": 268970,
      "dh_first_name": "MARK",
      "dh_last_name": "STAYTON",
      "ops_stop_recs": [ # contains array of their OpsStopRec instances
        {
          "ops_stop_id": 268973,
          "ops_order_id": "133204.0",
          "ops_type": "P",
          "ops_driver1": 61,
          "opl_amount": "2375.9"
        },
        {
          "ops_stop_id": 268973,
          "ops_order_id": "133204.0",
          "ops_type": "P",
          "ops_driver1": 61,
          "opl_amount": "2375.9"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```